# SQL Query to find top 5 cumulative tweets

Tags: mysql, sql

How to find the top 5 months with the highest number of cumulative tweets and sort it according to the number of tweets of each month.

Table twitter structure is like this:

```
Token type  Month   count   Hash Tag Name
hashtag     200910  2   Babylove
hashtag     200911  2   babylove
hashtag     200912  90  babylove
hashtag     200812  100 mycoolwife
hashtag     200901  201 mycoolwife
hashtag     200910  1   mycoolwife
hashtag     200912  500 mycoolwife
hashtag     200905  23  abc
hashtag     200907  1000 abc
```

Output should be like this

```
 month  numtweets
200907  1000
200912  590
200901  201
200812  100
200905  23
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: *Find the top 5 months with the highest number of cumulative tweets* ORDER BY + LIMIT

Comment: I'm sure you can answer this test question yourself. If you haven't attempt anything yet, start trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
SELECT Month,SUM(count) as numtweets
FROM twitter 
GROUP BY Month
ORDER BY numtweets DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: No FROM clause?

Comment: jarlh was right, I was missing the table :) I assume it is called twitter

Comment: See 2nd line of output, it's different than yours. Please refer Input and output data.

Comment: The results are the same. Based on the info you provided the output matches to what you expect on the question:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c18d91/1

Comment: Sorry my bad,Thanks a lot. can you explain the functionality of SUM(count)?

Answer (score 0):

I Guess it should be something like this if you use SQL Management :

```
SELECT TOP 5 Month, SUM(count) as number_tweets
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY Month
ORDER BY number_Tweets DESC
```

But if you use PHPmyadmin for your database then you should use the below code :

```
SELECT Month, SUM(count) as number_tweets
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY Month
ORDER BY number_Tweets DESC
LIMIT 5
```

This happens because PHPmyadmin doesn't support the "TOP" Clause, i tried this code for my database and it worked

Comment: I also thought same as you,
but 2nd row output is not match with our output.

Please refer input and output data.

Comment: The output should be the top 5 rows with the hightest "count" value and grouped by "month", did you try the query, if you did what was the result ?

Comment: Oh, if that is the output you want you just need the above code then, this code shall give you the output you need and you posted on your question

Comment: In 2nd row the numTweets should be 590 instead of 500.

Comment: So you want to Sum the number of the tweets for a month no matter the hashtag ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try as following

```
SELECT Token_type,Month,count, HashTag,cnt, SUM(cnt) AS cumulative
FROM (SELECT Token_type,Month,count, HashTag, COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM tweets
      GROUP BY Month) AS b
GROUP BY Month
ORDER BY cumulative DESC;
```

Comment: What's the use of As b?
we're not using anywhere else.

Comment: In MySql we have to give a table alias, if not the query fails

Comment: count(*) needs every other column name should be in group by clause.
It's throwing exception that token_type is not in group by.

Comment: I did it with an old version of MySQL that permits that.